# A word that means "of or related to an agenda"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for an adjective that would most closely mean "of, or related to, an agenda" - or, a nontrivial phrase (e.g. not just "agenda related").

Comment: *Agenda* is ambiguous here; it can be used in the sense of promoting some (usually hidden and often ideologically-based) idea, or it can simply mean, the set of things that are to be discussed. The first meaning is rather pointed, while the second is innocuous. I cannot tell from the context which it is you mean.

Comment: One wants to say "agendal", but alas it's not a recognized word.  "Scheduled", "planned", or "docketed" is probably about as close as one can get, for an item.  For other senses one would need to know the context.

Comment: *agendawise*...

Answer (score 1):

How about **programmatic**?

From Dictionary.com:

> [**programmatic**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/programmatic?s=t):
>   of, having, advocating, resembling, or following a *plan*, policy, or
>   *program*
>
> [**program**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/program?s=t): a *plan*
>   or schedule of activities, procedures, etc., to be followed

[Thesuarus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/agenda?s=t) lists both *plan* and *program* as synonyms of *agenda*. One could certainly read **programmatic** as meaning "of, or related to, an agenda".

Comment: Salutations, etc., etc.

Comment: @PeterPoint Ditto, etc., etc., if that not redundant. :-) Love your sense humor. Have to sign off for the night. Gunga Din: "Later, gator. "

Comment: In a while, crocodile!

Answer (score 0):

Might we not use the phrase **terms of reference** when dealing with an agenda?

As in, for example, "The committee voted to expand the US Federal Bank's **terms of reference** of its agenda to investigate the causes of the collapse of many financial institutions on Wall Street".

**Terms of reference:** Terms of reference (TOR) define the purpose and structure of a project, committee, meeting, or any similar collection of people who have agreed to work together to accomplish a shared goal (Wikipedia)